# How to filter text content on copy/paste operation in a editable component (vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have implemented a component that use contenteditable="true" to get possibility of edit content on this div (like a textarea).

Follow a snippet from my code:

```js
export default {
  name: 'divArea',
  props: ['value'],
  mounted() {
    this.$el.innerHTML = this.value;
  },
  methods: {
    updateHTML(e) {
      const html = e.target.innerHTML;
      this.$emit('input', html);
    },
  },
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div contenteditable="true"
    v-once
    v-html="value"
    @input="updateHTML"
    @paste="onPaste"
    class="txtArea"></div>
</template>
```

I’m trying to implement a paste feature in this area to copy a block of content from an html page but I would like to have only text version after paste operation (no html).

Currently I use v-html attribute with a prop on my component because I need to add an html custom tag on pasted text but only if user click on a button.

How can I do to implement this behavior?

Comment: You might want to look into Vue markdown, [here's an example](https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/).

Comment: Thank you @jom but this example use a library (marked.js)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First `contenteditable` is a real **Devil** and I recommend to not use it but anyway that was my solution

```
        let contenteditable = document.querySelector('[contenteditable]')
        contenteditable.addEventListener('paste', function(e){           
            // Prevent the default pasting event and stop bubbling            
            e.preventDefault()
            e.stopPropagation()
            // Get the clipboard data
            let paste = (e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('text/plain')

            // Do something with paste like remove non-UTF-8 characters            
            paste = paste.replace(/\x0D/gi, "\n")          
            e.target.textContent += paste
        })
```

the second part if you want to add the paste where the `cursor` was

```
  instead of 
            e.target.textContent += paste
```

you can use `Selection()`

```
       // Find the cursor location or highlighted area
        const selection = window.getSelection()
        // Cancel the paste operation if the cursor or highlighted area isn't found
        // if (!selection.rangeCount) return false
        // Paste the modified clipboard content where it was intended to go            
        if(selection.getRangeAt(0).collapsed){
            // TextareaManager.AddToCursor(document.createTextNode(paste))
            if(selection.getRangeAt(0).endContainer.nodeName != "DIV"){
                selection.getRangeAt(0).insertNode(document.createTextNode(paste))
            }else {
                e.target.childNodes[0].textContent += paste
            }
            selection.getRangeAt(0).collapse(false)
        }else {
           e.target.appendChild(document.createTextNode(paste))
        }
```

Comment: Thank you @mooga it seems a great start point to my issue. I don't like it that text content lost carriage return, but i can work on it. What can you suggest me to use in security contenteditable? sanitize that stripe html tags is not enought?

Comment: @sergioska, you don't lose the carriage return , just replace every `\n` with `<br/>` 
instead

Comment: you can't secure contenteditable but what you should do that you secure it from the backend side by filtering the inputs

Comment: Ok @mooga on that side i'm safe, because there isn't a backend side in this application :)

Answer (score 0):

> but I would like to have only text version after paste operation (no
>   html).

You can create a `DOM` element or use `DOMParser()` to set the `value` of the `<textarea>` and get the `.textContent` of the element.

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");
let parser = new DOMParser();
let parsedHTML = parser.parseFromString(textarea.value, "text/html");
console.log(parsedHTML.body.textContent);
```

```html
<textarea style="width:240px;height:50px;">
  <div>a<span>b</span><b>c</b></div>
</textarea>
```